# Main section not stretching all the way to bottom causing footer to not sit at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I know there are a lot of similar questions on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to figure out how to get it working on my page. the `<footer>` stays behind like 800px up from the bottom behind `<main>`. `<main>` won't reach all the way to the bottom even with `100%, fit-content` or any other height.

I simply want a normal footer at the bottom of my page.

if I put the footer inside the main div it does work but this is not recommended.

Does anyone see the problem?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.723);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0px 100px 0px 120px;
  color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

main {
  height: auto;
}

.expgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 50px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  row-gap: 50px;
  height: fit-content;
}

.exp {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #29292c;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<main>Main Content</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=CSS+footer+behind+not+at+bottom+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Start with `footer { ....   position: fixed; bottom: 0px; }` - you have a header that is fixed and the main is behind too

Comment: First of all, thanks for the tip on how to ask questions. Your solution does pin my footer to the bottom but now it is sticky (like my header) and just scrolls over the page. I want it to be static at the bottom.

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements

Comment: it's not about the z-index it's more about the footer not sticking on the bottom but instead appearing behind elements in the middle of the main section

Comment: because you have nothing in your styles that would push it to the bottom?  As it stands it is working exactly as I would expect - it sits below main and behind your header because your header is position fixed at the top

Comment: So the problem for me is that it doesn't sit below main but instead sits behind the grid in the middle of another div @Pete . Basically the .expgrid div is expanding beyond the main causing the footer to be in the middle of that div but behind it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a sticky header and footer then I would use `position: sticky` with a flex body, this way anything in your main will be scrollable and always sit behind the header and footer.

One thing to note is that I wouldn't use an opaque background colour on the header, otherwise you will see the main content when it scrolls behind it.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

footer {
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  main top<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: The issue still persists. My main section is not stretching all the way to the bottom and the grid is continuing underneath the main section. My footer is thus placed underneath the main section but behind and in the middle of the grid of items.

Comment: then you need to create a [mcve] demonstrating your issue as the code you have provided shows nothing of this grid -  as you can see from my answer, the main section stretches all the way to the bottom (use full screen to see it with less content than screen size)